# Cypress in node_modules overwriting zx's value for global `$` variable even though I'm not importing it

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, node-modules

I have zx and Cypress installed. Zx defines `$` as a command runner and Cypress defines `$` as JQuery. I'm not importing Cypress types anywhere, but when I use zx's `$`, I'm getting errors like `Property 'stdout' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLSelectElement>'.`. After uninstalling Cypress, these errors go away.

I tried adding Cypress to `exclude`, but it didn't work. Here's the relevant parts of my TSConfig:

tsconfig-base.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "strict": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": false,
    "lib": ["es2021"],
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
    ],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./node_modules/cypress/types/jquery",
  ],
}
```

scripts/tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig-base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "zx",
    ],
  },
  "include": [
    ".",
  ],
}
```

Comment: Your original title and the fact that you only include `tsconfig` files in your question means you are presuming the cause of the problem even though you do not know / have not proven that TS is the problem. You can easily produce an [mre] that narrows the source of the problem by copying your project and stripping the code down until the problem goes away. Conversly you can create a new project with both Cypress and zx and the above tsconfigs and very minimal code that imports zx only to prove that TS is auto-importing Cypress.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript does not do "auto imports", and this has nothing to do with Typescript configs and everything to do with code that is importing Cypress or JQuery directly or indirectly, as well as the order of import, because the one imported later will overwrite the globally set `$` with its value.

First clue: You have Cypress installed for a reason. ***That means something is using it.** The fact that uninstalling it changes the behavior proves this.

Remember, Typescript/Javascript imports are transitive/recursive. If you import A, and A imports B and B imports C, the script for C will execute before the script for B which will execute before the script for A.

Also: [tsconfig exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude) does not behave the way you think it does:

> Important: `exclude` only changes which files are included as a result of the [include](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) setting. A file specified by `exclude` can still become part of your codebase due to an `import` statement in your code, a `types` inclusion, a `/// <reference directive`, or being specified in the files list.
>
> It is not a mechanism that prevents a file from being included in the codebase - it simply changes what the include setting finds.

Comment: All very correct. Library authors really shouldn't be using globals like this. We've had RequireJS for over 15 years and these lib authors cling to their global dollar sign like I clung to my ex-girlfriend.